# Merge folder from one branch into another with git

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-diff, git-cherry-pick

I'm working with two branches in a git repository.

They are `rc` and `dev`.

I have a folder in `dev` `src/` that I need to merge into `rc`.

I've tried to use `git cherry-pick --strategy=recurisve --strategy-option=theirs <commit>` method by first creating a shell script to add a new line to all the files in the directory to trigger a change with git.

The script was as follows:

```
#/bin/sh

SEARCH_FOLDER="src/*"

for f in $(find $SEARCH_FOLDER);
do
    echo "" >> $f;
done;
```

What I did not realize is that `git cherry-pick` is only going to take the recognized changes vis-a-vis the aforementioned newlines.

Aside from just copying the folder over into a branch of `rc` and then creating a commit and merging, what are my options to push my changes that I've been working on in `dev` for two weeks into the `rc` branch.

I understand that the way I have been developing and using git is probably inappropriate and not intended use.

Ideally, I'd like to create a patch file using the diff on the two branches subfolders `src/` and apply it. Though, I'm not sure how to execute this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to grab the whole `src` folder from `rc` into `dev` like this:

While on your `rc` branch:

`git checkout dev -- src/`